# a range instead of equals for a render syntax

Tags: jsf, render

i have got a render that looks at a bean and if it is the same as a value above then it will render or not, this is working fine :

```
rendered="#{formBean.number eq 1}
```

what i want to do now though, is add if it is in a range, between 1 and 8 for example, is this possible if so what is the syntax as a quick google haven't shown up any results

Thanks

Comment: Um, what about `formBean.number ge 1 and formBean.number lt 8`?

Comment: Perfect thanks it worked, change it to 9 to include 8 in the range but all working great now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `le` (less equal) and `ge` (greater equal) in java EL to achieve this:

```
rendered="#{formBean.number ge 1 and formBean.number le 8}
```